# AP-controller through switch

Tags: networking, wifi

I am looking to use a H3C WX3024E controller for the wireless network. The building will require about 48 AP. The question is; since the controller only has 24 ports, do I use 2 controllers or can the AP units connect into a switch then into the controller?

I am new to building large networks.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between a so-called "wireless controller" and related "access-points" heavily depends on the technical implementation built by the vendor in its own products. As such, unfortunately, the word "wireless controller" is way-too-general, and can easily represents very different architectures. As an example, a Cisco "Wireless LAN Controller" is very very different from yours.

Back to your question.

"*since the controller only has 24 ports, do I use 2 controllers or can the AP units connect into a switch then into the controller?*"

On the [official datasheet](http://www.h3c.com/portal/download.do?id=737562) you can see:

- page 13, Performance indices, Maximum number of APs that can be managed: 48 (by upgrading the license)

so, at least, you need an additional license.

Also, please note that:

- page 10, Network Interconnection:

  - Roaming: Supporting roaming inside an AC; Supporting roaming between ACs; Supporting Key cache fast roaming

base on this, I bet that it will mostly impossible to properly support roaming (as intended by H3C) if remote APs are connected to common ethernet-switches ***AND*** you don't have enough licenses. In other words, to support roaming (again: in the H3C way), your APs needs to be fully managed by the AC and... this means, at least, you need to have proper licensing in place.

*(BTW: I stressed the concept "roaming in the H3C way" as it's really normal, for a wireless client, to associate to a different wireless-lan as soon as the wireless signal becomes lower than a predefined threshold, defined/managed by the wireless driver. So, wireless roaming, can also be intended... as a "free" feature provided by the wireless client. Unfortunately a deep discussion of this "feature" is a matter for a completely different question)*

A final note, based on your last statement: "*I am new to building large networks*": please consider spending **less** on the hardware and investing what you save on "professional services"